# не создаются элементы в HTML через JS, если подгружать модули

Tags: javascript, html

Не создаются элементы в `HTML` через `JS`, если подгружать модули
через `JS` элементы. Если в начале скрипта подключить какой-либо модуль, то ничего не работает. что делать?

```
var fs = require('fs'); /* Если убрать эту строку, то все работает*/

var cardBack=document.createElement('img');
```

Comment: Ошибки в консоли есть?

Comment: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require

Answer (score 3):

Функция `require()` не реализована в браузерах, это функция [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/).

Для подключения скриптов в браузере, используется либо HTML-тег `<script src="путь/к/скрипту">`, либо оператор [**`import`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) (ES6+).
Сейчас обычно используется первый способ (а второй -  только с компиляцией через [Babel](http://babeljs.io/)).

---

***p.s.:** JavaScript на странице, не имеет доступа к файловой системе клиента... это ограничение введено из соображений безопасности. На сервере (в Node.js) таких ограничений нет.*

Comment: И `fs` - это стандартный модуль Node.js (его в браузерах тоже нет).